# Custom sequence generators for PK on both entities having OneToOne mapping throws exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following two entities -

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.entity;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class Instructor {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="my_custom",strategy = "com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.MySequenceGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="my_custom")
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;


    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String email;


    @OneToOne(targetEntity=InstructorDetail.class, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;

    public InstructorDetail getInstructorDetail() {
        return instructorDetail;
    }


    public void setInstructorDetail(InstructorDetail instructorDetail) {
        this.instructorDetail = instructorDetail;
    }


    public Instructor() {

    }


    public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instructor [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }



}
```

InstructorDetail -

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
public class InstructorDetail {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="my_custom_2",strategy = "com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.MySequenceGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="my_custom_2")
    @Column(name="id")
    private String Id;


    @Column(name="youtube_channel")
    private String youtubeChannel;

    @Column(name="hobby")
    private String hobby;

    public InstructorDetail() {

    }

    public InstructorDetail(String youtubeChannel, String hobby) {
        this.youtubeChannel = youtubeChannel;
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getYoutubeChannel() {
        return youtubeChannel;
    }

    public void setYoutubeChannel(String youtubeChannel) {
        this.youtubeChannel = youtubeChannel;
    }

    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InstructorDetail [Id=" + Id + ", youtubeChannel=" + youtubeChannel + ", hobby=" + hobby + "]";
    }



}
```

Following is the custom sequence generator class (Note - I have been able to generate custom ID using this for a setup of a single entity class)-

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.*;
import org.hibernate.id.*;

public class MySequenceGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
        try {
            //System.out.println("Class name is "+object.getClass().toString());
            String tableName;
            if(object.getClass().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("class com.luv2code.hibernate.entity.Instructor")) {
                tableName = "Instructor";
            }
            else
            {
                tableName = "InstructorDetail";
            }
            Long total = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(1) from "+tableName).uniqueResult();

            Long nextVal = total+1l;
            return "append_"+nextVal.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Main method -

```
package com.luv2code.hibernate.demo;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.luv2code.hibernate.entity.Instructor;
import com.luv2code.hibernate.entity.InstructorDetail;

public class HibernateCutomGenDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class).addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class).buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println("Add New Employee");
            Instructor newEmployee = new Instructor("Sandeepan","Nath","email");
            newEmployee.setInstructorDetail(new InstructorDetail("link","hobby"));

            session.save(newEmployee);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            //sessionFactory.close();

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exception sequences repeated infinitely (just grabbed one section) -

```
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:148)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:81)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$$Lambda$65/935520971.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1325)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1405)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.uniqueResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1575)
at com.luv2code.hibernate.demo.MySequenceGenerator.generate(MySequenceGenerator.java:24)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:100)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$$Lambda$71/1544518128.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:614)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:607)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:158)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:148)
```

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @SternK 5.4.16.Final